# How can I load a CSS file in my NativeWindow?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have a Flex application with a main class that is a `WindowedApplication`. The CSS file is loaded using the `<fx:Style source="defaults.css">` tag in the MXML.

However, when this main class will open a `NativeWindow`, the CSS does not get applied. I have a subclass of `NativeWindow` where I can add some things, but this is ActionScript, not MXML. Is there an equivalent of `<fx:Style/>` for AS? Or do I have to do things in a different way?

UPDATE:
None of the proposed solutions so far seem to be working. I will try to write a small test app to show the behaviour, maybe it is a bug in the Flex framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to load the styles via a compiled stylesheet (as a SWF). You can compile a stylesheet to a SWF with MXMLC (mxmlc stylesheet.css). Then use StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(swf) to load and apply the styles.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do all styling with

```
someComponent.setStyle("someProperty", "someValue");
```

There's also a [StyleSheet](You can use [StyleSheets parseCSS method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html) class that you could use but it only applies to TextField elements IIRC

Comment: Do you mean I would have to copy everything from my CSS file (which is more then 1000 LOC) into this way? Seems like there should be a better way hopefully!

Comment: Well, you could parse the CSS file and then iterate over the properties. Some semi-pseudocode: `for each (var cssClass:Object in css:CssStyleSheet){ switch(cssClass.componentName){ case "textField": for each ( var property:Object in cssClass.properties){ myTextField1.setStyle(property.name, property.value); myTextField2.setStyle(property.name, property.value);}  break; case "someOtherComponentGroup": // and so on`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using global selectors in your CSS?

like

```
global {
    color: #000000;
}
```

or

```
s|Button
{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 skinClass:ClassReference("com.what.skins.ButtonSkin");
}
```

I have these things in my main application file in a style block and they are applied to all views